# Hyperlink within div tag

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I have a div in my html page as seen below

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p1> test </p1>
    <div id="text-input" contenteditable="true"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What i want to be able to do is if you type a website link inside the div, it turns into a clickable hyperlink taking you to the page. I have no idea how to do this and help is appreciated. thank you

Comment: I had posted a pure JS solution that doesn't need any libraries and does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you're trying to do isn't simple. First of all, a clickable hyperlink is something that needs an anchor tag `<a>` and by making contenteditable as true, you cant simply type `<a>...`, You might want to look into using some libraries such as QuillJS or SlateJS.

The following is an example of QuillJS, if you need to links to be auto-converted, you'd need to use another library that extends Quill's logic

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{
        header: [1, 2, false]
      }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block', 'link']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow' // or 'bubble'
});
```

```css
#editor-container {
  height: 375px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.7.1/katex.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/monokai-sublime.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.7.1/katex.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>




<div id="editor-container">
</div>
```

Edit: Here is a simple example in relation to your comment-

```js
$('#textinput').keyup(function() {
  
  var val = $('#textinput').val();
   
  $('#text').html(val)
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textinput" placeholder="Start typing here...
">
</textarea>

<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: would it instead be possible to mirror everything from the contenteditable div into something like a`<p1>` (or any other) tag where that then has the hyperlink if the user has typed in a url?

Comment: You can definitely mirror what you type into the div into another element, at which point, you should just use <textarea> instead of div contenteditable. However the problem is that you still need to be able to process the text to add an <a> tag automatically. Perhaps with regex. However in saying that, it can still work if you manually type `<a>... `

Comment: I've added a simple example of mirroring

Answer (score 1):

What you can do you can use regex expression to match if it is url typed by any user like below

```
var regExUrl = /https?:\/\/([\w\d-\.]+)?[\w\d-\.]+\.{1}[\w]{1,4}((\/{1})?)([a-zA-Z0-9&-@_\+.‌~#?\/=]*)?/gi;

var linkdiv = document.getElementById('text-input');

div.onkeyup = function () {

   if (div.innerHTML.match(regExUrl)) {

       $("linkdiv").addClass("url");

   } else {

       $("linkdiv").removeClass("url");
   }

}

$('.url').click(function(){
   window.open($(this).html(), '_blank');
});
```

and css you can use

```
.url{
   text-decoration: underline;
   color: blue;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your looking for a pure javascript its something like:

```
<form onsubmit="return access()">
<input type="text" id="link" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
function access(){
window.location = document.getElementById('link').value;
return false;
}
</script>
```

the function should always return false to stop the default form submission. if you want to do an easier way of doing this you could also use some libraries like jquery or angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to check if the content is a valid link if so surround it with an anchor tag.

Simple Use Case:

1. if a valid link
2. If an invalid link

Play with onChange property of Javascript.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your pure JS solution:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
        #text-input {
            border-left: 4px solid green;
            text-indent: 7px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p1> test </p1>
    <div id="text-input" contenteditable="true"></div>
    
    <script>
      let div = document.getElementById('text-input');
      let anchor;

      div.addEventListener('blur', event => {
        let text = div.innerText;
        div.innerText = '';
        anchor = document.createElement('a');
        div.appendChild(anchor);
        anchor.innerText = text;
        anchor.href = text.indexOf('https://') == 0 ? text : 'https://' + text;
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```